# Is it normal to write automation for compression?

Tags: production

Is it normal to write automation for compression/limiter?Or you can automate everything if it's right.

Comment: If you need to adjust the parameters down the track, then automate it. If you don't… don't. There's no "rule".

Comment: Do you mean to ask "if I find myself wanting to automate compressor parameters, is it a sign that I'm doing something wrong"?

Comment: @piiperi no. i want to automate master limiter but not sure 100%.

Comment: What are you not sure about?

Comment: Not only is it "normal", it is also very common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your *comment*

> i want to automate master limiter but not sure 100%

I'd actually say this is probably a bad idea. The purpose of a master limiter is, well, to *limit the master level*. It isn't really an effect so much as a safeguard. IMO the master limiter should be set up in such a way that it makes best use of the distribution mediums dynamic range. There are reasons why this is traditionally done by the *mastering engineer*, not by the mixing engineer.

If you find that the limiter is pumping excessively in one section but hardly does anything in another, then this is something that *might* make sense to tackle with automation – but not of the limiter but of the mixing levels. Obviously, the limiter only takes action when the signal actually gets to the limit. This may be down to a single track in your mix, in which case it can make sense to automate the level of that track down at this spot. Or maybe you should work with a multiband compressor before the limiter. Or...

> is it normal to write automation for compression

yes it is, in particular for *channel compressors*. In fact I tend to prefer automating compressor thresholds over automating channel levels, because it better preserves the perceived loudness of a channel while still adjusting the “firepower” of that channel. In particular, to get back at the master-limiter example: if one channel pumps the master limiter at one place in the song, it's probably a good idea to tame that channel with an individual compressor. And automating the threshold of that compressor can be a good way of adjusting how much the channel drives the master compression, without incuring a very notable change in the mixing ratios.